# Extracting the line and column number from a loc

Tags: rascal

I guess the titles says it all.
In my program I have a bunch of loc's and I would like to extract the line numbers / column numbers from them.

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
rascal>myLoc = |project://HelloWorld/src/ByeWorld.java|(24,669,<3,0>,<45,1>);
loc: |project://HelloWorld/src/ByeWorld.java|(24,669,<3,0>,<45,1>)

rascal>myLoc.begin
tuple[int line,int column]: <3,0>

rascal>myLoc.begin.line
int: 3

rascal>myLoc.begin.column
int: 0
```

See also: http://tutor.rascal-mpl.org/Rascal/Expressions/Values/Location/Location.html